# When is the spectral measure absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

According to Bochner's theorem, the covariance function $b(t)$ of a centered, weakly stationary process $X(t)_{t\geq 0}$ can be written as

$$b(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t \lambda} \mu(d\lambda),$$

where $\mu$ is the spectral measure of the process.

Which properties of $X(t)$ are sufficient for $\mu$ being absolutely continuous w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure?